# Doesnt get the input field OOP Class

Tags: php, input-field

I hope somebody can help me, i am oop starter and the script below gives output `<` but i want this `<input type="text">`.

Now i created a Build class but it doesnt work. What do i do wrong and how can i fix this?
Can somebody help me?
Thnks!

```
//set get Element
class Element {
    private $_element; 

    function addElement($element) {
        $this->_element = $element;
    }

    function getElement(){
        return $this->_element;
    }
}
```

```
//add and set Atrr
class attrType extends Element {
    //set var 
    public $_attrType;

    function __construct(){     
        $this->_attrType = array(); 
    }

    function addAttr($attrType, $attrValue){
        $this->_attrType[$attrType] = $attrValue;
    }

    function getAttr(){
        return $this->_attrType;
    }
}
```

```
//build input text field
class Build extends attrType {
    function Builder() {
        $html .= "<";
        $html .= ''.$this->getElement();

        foreach( $this->getAttr() as $key => $value){       
            $html .= " $key=";
            $html .= "\"$value\">";
        }

        return $html;
    }    
}

$element = new Element();
$attr = new attrType();
$build = new Build();

$attr->addElement('input');
$attr->addAttr('type','text');
echo $build->Builder();
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is never a good  problem description. What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: You are calling `addElement` and `addAttr` on one object and calling `Builder` on another object.

Comment: the problem is that it shows < but is has to be <input type="text"> So the builder class doesnt work, this->getElement() and $this->getAttr()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as shown below

```
$build->addElement('input');
$build->addAttr('type','text');
```

instead of

```
$attr->addElement('input');
$attr->addAttr('type','text');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are creating separate objects and expecting them to share properties, that's the problem. If you change your last 3 lines to this, your code will work:

```
$build->addElement('input');
$build->addAttr('type','text');
echo $build->Builder();
```

[Codepad demo here](http://codepad.org/H9RbQXx7)

Although the code works, IMO it's not the best way to do it. When inheriting, a good rule of thumb is to to ask yourself: can the derived class be considered the class that it derives from? In other words is a `Builder` an `Element`, I don't think it is. For me a `Builder` would take an element and build the HTML and so I wouldn't derive `Builder` from `Element`.

A good example of inheritance in this case would be to have your base `Element` class, then derive specific elements from it such as `TextInput`, `TextArea`, `RadioButton`. Each of those can be considered an `Element`, and therefore would be a good choice for inheritance.

Be careful not to overcomplicate things too much, OOP doesn't mean make it difficult. What are the benefits to a Builder class? If you can't name any then just use a `build()` or `toHTML()` method on the parent class.

Comment: Anyway is this good OOP to build a complete form? And i get this notice Notice: Undefined variable: html in C:\websites\..... on line 39

Comment: @BasDL I've edited the answer with some more info.

Comment: @MrCode, you mean that the build method shoot be in the element class? This all is for me a practise, so tips are welcome!

Comment: @BasDL it could be in the Element class yes, but having a Builder class is OK so long as you think it's beneficial. I wouldn't derive Builder from Element though because of what I said in the answer. In OOP, not all classes need to extend another class, just extend when it's logical to do so.

Comment: OK, clear, thanks, again a step further!

Comment: @BasDL if this answer solved your problem you can mark it as accepted, by clicking the tick next to the answer.

Comment: @MrCode , in the script we also dont need $element = new Element();
$attr = new attrType(); , right?

Comment: @BasDL Correct because Builder is extending attrType which in turn extends Element. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: Ok thanks! Where can i do that, accepting, iam new here ;-)

Comment: @BasDL no problem, welcome to SO. You can accept the answer by clicking the tick symbol to the left of my answer.

Comment: @BasDL is there any reason you changed your accepted answer?